# Wso2 IS 5.10 SAML grant type not getting claims in jwt token(OAUTH2) but visible in JWT Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 IS 5.10 I have a claim skype which is a local claim which I am returning from saml assertion as a attribute. But using SAML grant type if I generate OAuth2 token by exchanging SAML Assertion I am not getting claim skype in jwt token as claims.

[image]

I have added a skype claim in openidscope as a external scope also and also I have added skype claim as requested claim in service provider.But then also in jwt token claim is not returning.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are checking the requested claims on the JWT access token requested using the saml-bearer grant.
Self Contained access token in saml-bearer grant won't return the user claims is a known issue tracked in;

- https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6321 and
- https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12131

You should be able to retrieve the claim values in the id token as mentioned in the above issue descriptions.